# Tween color overlay of Spine animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, spine

Im using Unity3D and character animations imported from Spine. I want to add a color overlay over those characters. For example, I have one character, I want to make it a "shadow" character, so I add the black color over it in this way:

```
GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation>().Skeleton.color = new Color(0f,0f,0f);
```

Nevertheless, I want a Tween between the regular color, and the new color. But, unfortunately, I can't do it with the DOColor method of DOTween. I try

```
GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation>().Skeleton.DOColor(Color.Black,1);
```

But the method DOColor for Skeleton doesn't exists. So which is the way to follow to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoColor, DoMove, etc are shortcuts and extension method that written for unity's built-in components. `SkeletonAnimation` is not supported by DoTween extension methods. You can tween its color property like this:

```cs
Color yourColor = Color.white; //GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation>().Skeleton.color
Color targetColor = Color.black;
float duration = 1f;
DOTween.To(() => yourColor, co => { yourColor = co;  }, targetColor, duration);
```

Also, You can write your own extension:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions{

    public static Tweener DOColor(this SkeletonAnimation target, 
    Color endValue, float duration)
    {
    DOTween.To(() => target.color, 
               co => { target.color = co; }, 
               endValue, 
               duration);   
    } 


}
```

Comment: Well, I found an easiest way... DOTween.To(getter,setter,endValue, duration) and that's it, not writting the extension, just that command. And it works! As is based on your answer, I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with UI, For SkeletonGraphic, following code works.

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static void DOColor(SkeletonGraphic skeletonGraphic, Color endValue, float duration)
    {
        DOTween.To(() => skeletonGraphic.color, 
            newColor => { skeletonGraphic.color = newColor; }, 
            endValue, 
            duration);
    }
}
```

And then you can call like:

```
private SkeletonGraphic _skeletonGraphic;

private void Start()
{
    _skeletonGraphic = spineAnimationParent.GetComponentInChildren<SkeletonGraphic>();
}

Utilities.DOColor(_skeletonGraphic, Color.grey, 0.5f);
```

It is important to NOT pass the color by value (i.e. _skeletonGraphic.color as input of DOColor function would be bad), because since you want to change the color inside of your class, you need to pass reach reference in Utilities.DOColor().